# Why must `report` occur at the top level of a NetLogo procedure?

Tags: netlogo

I wanted to write something like this.

```
to-report a-new-agent
  crt 1 [ 
    <do some stuff with it>
    report self
  ]
end
```

But that triggers a compiler error message: `report must be immediately inside a to-report`.  So I'm forced into something like this.

```
to-report a-new-agent
  let new-agent nobody
  crt 1 [ 
    <do some stuff with it>
    set new-agent self
  ]
  report new-agent
end
```

This works, but it's irritating to have to write work-around code like this. What is the reason for this limitation?

Comment: I can't tell you *why* it is like this, but I can tell you that this is something that the NetLogo development team is aware of: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1071